# How do I add a comma to figure values (for values > 1000)

Tags: r, r-markdown

I don't see an answer for R or markdown. I received for revisions for an article, and they want me to change the scale values to include a comma. Is this possible? Thus, it would be 337,500 rather than 337500, etc. Thanks much!

James

[image]

Here's the header and the entirety of the code segment (the most important part is below the actual AIC values):

```
#header

---
fig: no crop
geometry: left=1mm, right=1mm, top=1mm, bottom=1mm, asymmetric
indent: TRUE
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx: my-styles.docx 
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
    fig_caption: yes
    includes:
      in_header: my_header.tex
  pdf_document: default
header-includes: 
    - \usepackage{placeins}
    - \usepackage{indentfirst}
    - \usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing
    - \usepackage{lineno}
    - \linenumbers
---
```

```
cleanup = theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
                panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
                panel.background = element_blank(), 
                axis.line = element_line(color = "black"))

aic = c(AIC(logLik(ed_crime.model.v.p.int.pop)),AIC(logLik(ed_crime.model.v.p.int.pop_percap)), AIC(logLik(ed_crime.model.v.p.int.pop_ed)),
AIC(logLik(ed_crime.model.v.p.int.pop_off)),
AIC(logLik(ed_crime.model.v.p.int.pop_wht)),
AIC(logLik(ed_crime.model.v.p.int.pop_difdem)),
AIC(logLik(ed_crime.model.v.p.int.pop_blk)),
AIC(logLik(ed_crime.model.v.p.int.pop_mgr)),
AIC(logLik(ed_crime.model.v.p.int.pop_ba)),
AIC(logLik(ed_crime.model.v.p.int.pop_propov)),
AIC(logLik(ed_crime.model.v.p.int.pop_asian)),
AIC(logLik(ed_crime.model.v.p.int.pop_hs)),
AIC(logLik(ed_crime.model.v.p.int.pop_nghs)), AIC(logLik(ed_crime.model.v.p.int.pop_sc)), AIC(logLik(ed_crime.model.v.p.int.pop_mapl)), AIC(logLik(ed_crime.model.v.p.int.pop_unempl)), AIC(logLik(ed_crime.model.v.p.int.pop_medinc)))

variables <- c("Population + Pop Dense", "Per Capita Income", "Education Spending", "Law Enforcement", "White", "Political Leanings",  "Black", "Median Rent", "Education: BA", "Proportion 5-17 in Poverty", "Asian",  "Education: HS", "Education: did not graduate HS", "Education: some college","Education: MA/greater", "Unemployment", "Median Income") #"Complete Null", 
#, "Latino" "Two or more races",
df <- data_frame(variables = variables, AIC = aic)


colourCount = length(unique(df$variables))
getPalette = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "Dark2"))

a <- df%>%
  mutate(name = fct_reorder(variables, desc(AIC)))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = AIC, fill= variables))+
  geom_col()+
  coord_flip()+
  theme(legend.position="right")+
  xlab("Variables")+
  ylab("AIC (DV Crime)")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = getPalette(colourCount))+
  guides(fill=FALSE)+
  ggtitle("8a: Comparative Variance")+
  set_theme(title.size = .6)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = range(df$AIC),
                       oob = function(x, ...) x,
                       expand = c(0.2, 0)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 5),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 6),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 8),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 8))+
  cleanup
```

Comment: Use (example for 100000)      "scales::label_comma()(100000)"   You can edit it by adding "label" argument inside "scale_y_continuous"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, this should work!

```
scale_y_continuous(limits = range(df$AIC),
               oob = function(x, ...) x,
               expand = c(0.2, 0),
               labels = scales::label_comma())
```